# http Response Structure Zipped

Tags: http, http-headers

I've been dabbling with the underlying client-server communications (cURL, browsers, and server responses, among a variety of others). I think at this point I understand the basic structure of a request and response:

Request:

```
(Method) (File) (Protocol)
(Headers)
(Empty)
(Body?)
```

Response:

```
(Protocol) (Code) (Meaning)
(Headers)
(Empty)
(Body?)
```

This was working fine until I sent compressed information. More precisely, I used gzip to send HTML in the response.

First, I'm using an updated version of Chrome to test -- and if I use a prebuilt HTTP server solution, gzip (In exactly the way I'm using it now) works fine.

In the 'Accept-Encoding' header sent from Chrome, it states that it will accept gzip. My guess is there's something specific I haven't run across yet (And haven't been able to find through searching).

All that said, here's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 205

(Zipped data...)
```

If I remove gzip and leave everything else exactly the same, this works fine. The Content-Length is the length of the zipped data, not the raw data, though I commented that out to make sure it wasn't doing something I wasn't expecting. Chrome doesn't 'require' Content-Length to figure out what it wants to do.

At one stage, I also had `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` which didn't make a difference (Underneath the zip, the string is converted to utf-8 on the server).

Originally I zipped the headers *and* the body for consistency (And lowest-length). I figured it failed because the headers had to be visible to the browser to figure out the body would be zipped.

In both cases, however, Chrome displays "ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED" which is classic "We don't know how to decode the information."

Prior to trying to embed this into the same response, I sent the headers first and the body second, thinking that may be the best approach -- two different responses.

Chrome took this to mean the server was pushing downloadable content and entered an infinite acceptance loop, so clearly that wasn't the solution. In addition, the content it received wasn't used.

Technically, a normal web server would end the transmission after sending the second response, but I'm experimenting without that to better understand the connections.

Is there something I'm missing, or are there any thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Thanks!

*Edit*

The code is scattered out across various functions (I doubt anyone wants to look at ~300 lines), but I picked out the relevant pieces. Right before gzip, self.written is html.

```
const zipper = require('zlib');
push(value, callback)
{
  this.socket.write(value, callback);
}

let self = this;
zipper.gzip(self.written, function(error, zipped)
{
  self.setHeaders(
  {
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
    'Content-Length': zipped.length
  });

  self.getHeaderString(function(error, headers)
  {
    self.push(headers + zipped, callback);
  });
});
```

When I console.log the final response:

[image]

Comment: How are you compressing it? The error could suggest that there's something wrong with how you compressed it. You mention `zip` a few times, but it's _not_ the same as `gzip`.

Comment: @Evert I'm using Node.js `zlib.gzip`, which works fine if I use Node's built-in `http` module, but for some reason doesn't when I attempt to structure the response myself.

Comment: Maybe you are calling it differently. Based in your question I can tell you have a correct understanding of how it's supposed to work, so the problem is in your implementation. Share code.

Comment: @Evert I updated with the relevant code and a screenshot of the output given final result. If the response is 'correct,' I'll have to figure out what minor thing I missed. I just thought maybe there was a rule I wasn't able to find about responses, unique to compression.

Comment: The code you shared is definitely incorrect. Could you try sharing a sample that someone can run? It looks like a poor copy-paste. Ideal is a code sample that can be used to exactly reproduce your problem.